# Crosstabs with multiple response sets

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I'm using Python to try to create a function that calculates crosstabs using multiple response questions. Here's my thoughts until now:

Given a dictionary of variables that correspond to multiple response sets:

```
multiple_response_dict =  {
    'Q2': ['Q2_1', 'Q2_2', 'Q2_3'],
    'Q4': ['Q4_1', 'Q4_2', 'Q4_3', 'Q4_4', 'Q4_5', 'Q4_6','Q4_Outro'], 
}
```

I need to make a crosstab between each column of the multiple_respose_dict (Q2,Q4,...) and a given variable (which can be or not a multiple response)

if my dataset was something like this:

```
Q2_1    Q2_2    Q2_3       Q3
Na loja Email   Folheto    Sim
Na loja                    Não
Na loja Email              Sim
                Folheto    Sim
```

The output would be:

```
      Sim   Não
Na loja 2   1
Email   2   0
Folheto 2   0
```

I would also want to have the possibility of calculating it as % of column.

That being said, I'm trying to make a function that receives the dataset, the dictionary and the variable (that can be multiple response also or not) and if its percentage of column or absolute value.

I'm not sure if I'm thinking well using a dictionary, if not I'm more than open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're really after with the information you've provided but you can get your output from the example dataset using the following.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = '''Q2_1,Q2_2,Q2_3,Q3
Na loja,Email,Folheto,Sim
Na loja,,,Não
Na loja,Email,,Sim
,,Folheto,Sim'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',', engine='python')
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['Q3'], value_vars=['Q2_1' ,'Q2_2', 'Q2_3']).drop('variable' , axis=1)
dfg = dfm.groupby(['value', 'Q3']).agg(count=('value', 'count')).reset_index()
dff = pd.pivot_table(dfg, values='count', index=['value'], columns=['Q3'], aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0).reset_index()
dff
```

Output

```
Q3    value  Não  Sim
0     Email    0    2
1   Folheto    0    2
2   Na loja    1    2
```